# Service posting null values to the MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am trying to post a JSON object to my service, deserialize it and save it to the database. It works - kind of. The problem is that some fields of the JSON get saved to the database, while others are null.

For example, when posting this JSON:

```
{
"FirstName": "Michael",
"LastName": "Ledley",
"BirthPlace": "Austria",
"Gender": "M",
"OIB": "12348879991",
"CurrentPlace": "New Guinea",
"Department": "D_21570"
}
```

... in the database only `CurrentPlace`, `Gender` and `Department` are stored correctly, while all the other values (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `BirthPlace`, ...) are NULL. The type for all of them is `VARCHAR(45)`, the same as for the `CurrentPlace` which is stored properly.

The code that executes the saving looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
public class EmployeeApiController : ApiController
{

    readonly EmployeePersistence persistence;

    public EmployeeApiController()
    {
        persistence = new EmployeePersistence();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public void Post([FromBody] Employee employee)
    {
        // saving id for the debugging purposes
        long id = persistence.SaveEmployee(employee);
    }


    public long SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        string sqlString =
            "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, BirthPlace, CurrentPlace, Gender, Department, OIB) " +
            "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @BirthPlace, @CurrentPlace, @Gender, @Department, @OIB)";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", employee.FirstName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", employee.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthPlace", employee.BirthPlace);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentPlace", employee.CurrentPlace);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", employee.Gender == EmployeeGender.M ? 1 : 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", employee.Department.GetStringValue());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OIB", employee.OIB);

        ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
        return cmd.LastInsertedId;
    }

    void ExecuteSqlCommand(MySqlCommand cmd)
    {
        try
        {
            // execute the SQL command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            // log the error
            throw new Exception(
                String.Format("Error executing the command '{0}'. The error is '{1}'.",
                              cmd, e.Message));
        }
    }
```

Why are some values NULL and some not when saved in the database?

Comment: did you checked employee object value in SaveEmployee method ?

Comment: From some reason the debugger doesnt catch the call to that method, so I cant really check it. I'm new to visual studio so maybe im doing sth wrong with the debugger.

Comment: then add logging to where it is saved into the employee class, because it would sound like values arent making it into that class

Comment: It seems like values are not coming to controller itself. So may be you can put a break point on this method and try to debug. If you have issues with breakpoints then try to log the data to a file or something and make sure that data is coming correctly

Comment: @wesleyy breakpoint issue is only for this particular method ? or breakpoints are not at all hitting anywhere in code ?

Comment: They are not hitting anywhere. I am trying to fix that...

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to show the declaration of your `Employee` class -- at a minimum the data types of fields like `FirstName` and `BirthPlace`?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to populate your `Parameter` objects more completely.

Instead of ...

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);  
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", employee.FirstName);
  ...
```

Try this.

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn);  
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = employee.FirstName;
  ...
```

The point is to declare the parameters' data types and lengths explicitly.